# Serving static files in elastick beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a python3 flask application in aws elasitc beanstalk (Amazon Linux 2 platform). The folder structure is as follows:

```
|-app/
|-templates/
|-static/
|   |-css/
|   |-js/
|-app.py
```

In the template files, importing of static resources are defiled as:
i.e. JS file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
```

In the EB configurations, I've defined the static resources as below

[image]

But the problem is, these resources are not loading and giving 404.
i.e.: `https://example.com/static/js/jquery.js` cannot be loaded. But if I try `https://example.com/js/jquery.js`, it works.

Have I done the configurations wrong??

Comment: On Python platform `/static` path is set by default as static as explained in [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#python-platform-staticfiles). This maybe you shouldn't overwrite it?

Comment: That's correct Marcin. having the /static/ mapping was the error

Comment: Glad to hear. If you don't mind I will put it as an answer for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments.

The issue was due to **overwriting** `/static` path. In python EB environments, `/static` path is [used by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-container.html#python-platform-staticfiles) to server the static content:

> By **default**, the proxy server in a Python environment serves any files in a folder named static at the **/static path**. For example, if your application source contains a file named logo.png in a folder named static, the proxy server serves it to users at subdomain.elasticbeanstalk.com/static/logo.png. You can configure **additional mappings** as explained in this section.

The **solution** was to use the default settings and remove the overwrite.